# How move page counter from center to right for page which is generated by \tableofcontents command?

Tags: table-of-contents

How move page counter from center to right for page which is generated by `\tableofcontents` command?

[image]

Comment: Easy with `fancyhdr` package and `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}`, for example, but we need more information, and having the page number right on a verso page is a little bit unusual

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you very much!!! `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}` this command helped, but horizontal line arised in header of page. I removed this line via `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, "having the page number right on a verso page is a little bit unusual" It is requirement for diploma work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer With `oneside` it would not be unusual only with `twoside`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for answer from Christian Hupfer.

You can try next command

`\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}`

but after horizontal line can appered in footer of contents page.

You can remove it via next command

`\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`

Comment: I was aware about the horizontal rule there, but the comment slot is not the right place to give complete solutions...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, sorry, I'm new on the `tex.stackexchange.com`. Thank you very much again:)

Answer (score 1):

This is very ease with package `scrlayer-scrpage`. For the standard classes `book` all you need is `\ofoot[\pagemark]{}`. For single-sided documents (standard class `report` or standard class `book` with option `oneside`) you need an additional `\cfoot[]{}`.

```
\documentclass{book}% or \documentclass{report} or \documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% with automatic running heads
%\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% without automatic running heads
\ofoot[\pagemark]{}
\cfoot[]{}% not needed in this example
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Note, that is also changes the foot of other `plain` pages, like the first page of a chapter, but not pages with running heads:

[image]

Or with single-sided document (Contents page would be the same):

[image]